# Is there a Django app that can give me easy friend importing AND invite from Facebook, Twitter, and Gmail?

Tags: python, django, facebook, gmail

Super easy django app that just lets people click "Facebook", and then invite AND import their friends

Comment: I am looking for this too buddy...

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the pinax (http://pinaxproject.com/). They have a lot of reusable apps and one of those provide mechanism for inviting friends from openid based sites (i.e. facebook)